# Terms and condtions for magento2

Tags: magento2.3.0

how I can to remove or edit Terms and condition from database because it's not available

[image]

Comment: You may have some error on this page since I have found it works fine in my Magento 2.3 version. Please check by adding **`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`** in app/bootstrap.php or check the log files of Magento for more info.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you not able edit term& condition section or not able to create term condition section

Comment: Magento 2.3.0 Terms and Conditions working fine. Disable your custom and third party added module or your customization and check.